# how to hide status bar like google authenticator

Tags: ios

iOS 10, xcode 9.2

as the image shows, the statusbar hides in the front viewcontroller or window? but shows on the back viewcontroller.

i have tried hide statusbar, but both viewcontroller will hide the status.

[image: google auth]

Comment: Create a `UIWindow` with level `.statusBar + 1`.. Add your slide in controller to that and animate that window from the left of the screen to 1/3..

Comment: @Brandon thanks, vc transitioning in another window is another chanllenge.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not hidden the background of menu view is white like labels on status bar

bottom view controller is pinned to topLayoutGuide.bottom = 0

top view controller is pinned to superView = 0

see here

[image]

after click button

[image]

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delayed reply. Could you some post piece of code of a demo? Thanks

Comment: I've tried to create a new windows with `window_level = statusbar + 1`, that is a ugly way.